# How to retrive the transfer order details, with the sales order number in Sterling OMS?

Tags: ibm-sterling

I've a requirement where in, I need to get all the transfer orders, that has been associated with the sales order.

Is there any api / attribute in getOrderDetails API that has transfer order number or TransferOrderHeaderKey ?

In the input, I've both sales order number and orderHeaderKey.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use getOrderList call with a combination of documentType for Transfer Order and Derived_from_chained_order_header_key

Answer (score 0):

Using below input you would be able to get all the transfer orders by invoking getOrderList api

```
<Order DocumentType="0006">

<OrderLine ChainedFromOrderHeaderKey="<SalesOrderHeaderKey>"/>

</Order>
```